# Sencha Touch 2 Vs. Phonegap

Tags: mobile

We are in the process of analyzing the best platform for a Hybrid mobile application. The requirement will be an app that will be available on Android/iPhone/BB devices. On all other decvices, the mobile website can be accessed from the inbuilt browser.

I understand Sencha Touch does cover Android, iPhone and Blackberry devices - which means the mobile website will not be available from the browsers in the other devices (non-webkit browsers like Windows,Palm....)

While Phonegap has the compatibility across different browsers. I'm looking to see what advantages are of using Sencha over Phonegap considering all other features?

Comment: It's not a dichotomy. I'm using both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that PhoneGap is a framework which does not include an inbuilt UI framework. Instead, it just acts as a cross-platform wrapper for the native APIs, exposing you a Javascript based API to access native capabilities. With PhoneGap, you have the option of using pure HTML5, or using a UI framework such as Sencha Touch 2 itself, jQueryMobile, jQTouch, Kendo UI, etc. Sencha Touch on the other hand, is a UI framework, but it does not have the out of the box capability to expose a cross platform JavaScript API for the native capabilities.

From the below statement from you, I suppose you do not plan to access any native APIs in your application, and what you will be writing is a pure mobile web application.

> The requirement will be an app that will be available on
>   Android/iPhone/BB devices. On all other devices, the mobile website
>   can be accessed from the inbuilt browser.

If that is the case, I don't see any reason to use PhoneGap for your application. You could just write it entirely using Sencha Touch 2, and use it's build and packaging tools to package it for the target platforms.

However, if you are planning to use native APIs, then Sencha Touch 2 alone will not be able to provide you that capability, in which case you should wrap Sencha Touch 2 in a PhoneGap application. Have a look at this video from Sencha Docs regarding this http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/video/native-apis-from-touch

Comment: Thanks Yohan. This is what we ended up doing - write, build and package on Sencha.